# How to draw a button with it's width as MATCH_PARENT programatically?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, button

Here i'm trying to simply draw a button programmatically where it's width should be match parent but when i set it as match_parent nothing happens and my button simply disappears however if i set some value say 500 or 700 button is created successfully.

```
private void drawButtons(Canvas c, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        //float buttonWidthWithoutPadding = buttonWidth - 20;
        float corners = 16;

        View itemView = viewHolder.itemView;
        Paint p = new Paint();

        RectF leftButton = new RectF(itemView.getLeft(), itemView.getTop(), itemView.getLeft() + MATCH_PARENT, itemView.getBottom());
        p.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        c.drawRoundRect(leftButton, corners, corners, p);
        drawText("Hours Worked:"+" "+"", c, leftButton, p);
    }
    private void drawText(String text, Canvas c, RectF button, Paint p) {
        float textSize = 60;
        p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        p.setTextSize(textSize);

        float textWidth = p.measureText(text);
        c.drawText(text, button.centerX()-(textWidth/2), button.centerY()+(textSize/2), p);
    }
```

Comment: Explore LayoutParams to set height and width for button at runtime, this might help.

Comment: @ankitpurwar i can't use layout params here look at my code carefully i'm not holding any reference to a button the button is create at run time with paint and rectf

Comment: Why don't use `getWidth()`? It'll give the same effect